# Baked goods with Teff flour turn out gritty. How can I prevent this?

Tags: gluten-free

I like the idea of using Teff flour for its health properties but find that results are unpleasantly gritty.  It's as if I am using sand as a medium.
This is the [Teff Date Bread recipe](http://www.glutenfreeveganpantry.com/teff-date-bread-cookbook-review/) I tried, and I tried several different ones.

Can anyone suggest a solution?  Is it the brand that's faulty?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the brand, but flours which are sold for health purposes are often whole grain. If it has the bran milled together with the corn, there is no way around the grittiness.

I don't know if something like "teff cake flour" exists, as it is probably the opposite of what teff eaters want. You could try calling the producers of your brand and asking. Else see if cycling through brands helps. But for such a niche product, it might be that all brands do whole grain only.

Comment: Given its higher fibre content and the tiny size of its grains, it sounds like teff flour would have a significantly higher percentage of bran than other whole grain flours.

Answer (score 1):

In America's Test Kitchen's "[How Can it be Gluten Free](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936493616)", they mentioned that you typically have to give other flours extra time to soak before cooking.

They recommended giving your dough or batter a 30 minute rest before baking, so the flours fully hydrate.  This may also require adding additional liquid.

Comment: thank you for your advice.  will definitely give it a go - it sounds so logical.  I love logical... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know that if you heat teff flour and water to 65°C while stirring, the starches in the teff will fully hydrate and the grittiness disappears. I am told that if you mix teff flour with liquid and process in a blender at high speed for a minute the grittiness also is resolved but I have not verified the blender approach.